# Why won't a 3PL IRT run?

Tags: stata, item-response-theory

I'm running some IRT models on test data and encountered a new problem.
There are 36 items (scored as "correct" and "incorrect") and 287 participants with no missing data.
I'm using Stata (not by choice).

I can get a 1PL and a 2PL IRT model to run no problem, but the 3PL *just won't work*.
I get stuck running hundreds of iterations, all of which are not concave.  I tried adding the option "difficult" (use a different stepping algorithm in nonconcave regions) and even changing the start values, but to no avail.

Is this because I'm trying to estimate too many things and don't have enough people?  Or am I missing something else?

Note:  The code I'm running is basic, but it's:

. irt 1pl q1-q36

. irt 2pl q1-q36

. irt 3pl q1-q36

. irt 3pl q1-q36, startvalues(fixedonly) difficult

Comment: 3PL famously is hard to estimate unless you have a lot of subjects (many hundreds). One thing that it supposed to help a lot is to define an informative prior on the guessing parameter, or at least regularize it in some way. Not sure how or if that can be accomplished in Stata

Comment: Sometimes estimating a model well depends on more than just the number of items or people. Sometimes the issue relates to "aliasing": basically the 3 parameter model can create a very good fitting S-shaped curve to response probabilities under a large number of possible parametrizations. (e.g. b very small and c also very small vs. b very large yet c also very large both lead to approximately "linear" S-shaped curves).